# How in Vaadin 12 call JavaScript's method?

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin12

In my Vaadin 12 project:

```
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.HtmlImport
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JavaScript
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.StyleSheet
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.BodySize
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Page
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinRequest
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

@Route(value = "myform")
@JavaScript("https://somejavascript.js")
class MyForm : Div() {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    init {
        val request = VaadinRequest.getCurrent()
        val myparam= request.getParameter("myparam")
        logger.info("myparam = $myparam")

    }
}
```

As you can see I import script: `somejavascript.js` by annotation. 
Nice.
This script has method : `myJavaScriptMethod`
How I can call this method in my Vaadin class `MyForm` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call your JS function `myJavaScriptMethod()` with this code:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("myJavaScriptMethod();");
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v11/flow/advanced/tutorial-execute-javascript.html)
(strangely this documentation is only shown for the vaadin version 11, but it's still done the same way in Vaadin 12 and 13)

Comment: How I can pass one String param to this method?

Comment: based on the linked documentation, you can do this with `UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("myJavaScriptMethod($0);", myStringVariable);`

Comment: I try this: UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("myJavaScriptMethod($0);", myParam); - but I get error: (ReferenceError): myJavaScriptMethod is not defined

Comment: Then your javascript import did not work. I'm not sure if providing external js files work in the @JavaScript annotation. Can you download said js script and put it into your static resources folder?

Comment: Can you confirm that when you enter *the very same URL to the js file* into the browser, you get a js file (AKA is your url a valid url to a js script)?

Comment: The [API](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/13.0.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/dependency/JavaScript.html#value--) of the `@JavaScript` annotation states that absolute URL do work.

Comment: based on your new question, it seems you were able to make it work? Can you please share what it was? thanks

Comment: Now I get another errror: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478212/vaadin-12-javascript-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cant-encode-class-ja

Comment: I know thats what I meant. it implies that you do no longer get this error described here. How did you make it work? was the url to your js wrong or was it something else?